# Problem With UitableView Refreshing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, scrollview

I cant refresh tableView it is crashing without any exception.i am placing my code below.please let me know where i have gone wrong..

```
    -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        return 103;
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {
        if(indexPath.row==[self.NewsArray count])
        {
            MoreLoadingViewCell *cell = (MoreLoadingViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
            if(cell==nil)
            {
                [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MoreLoadingViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = moreViewCell;
                cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
                //cell.backgroundView=nil;
            }
            return cell;
        }
        else
        {
            NewsCell *newsCell = (NewsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NewsCell"];
            if (newsCell == nil) 
            {
                NSLog(@"create adcell object");
                [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewsCell" owner:self options:nil];
                newsCell=newsCellobject;

            }

            NewsObjectClass *object;
            object=[self.NewsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSString *title=[object valueForKey:@"title"];
            NSString *description=[object valueForKey:@"Description"];
            NSString *dateString=[object valueForKey:@"NewsDate"];
            newsCell.secondLabel.text=title;
            newsCell.thirdLabel.text=description;
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
            NSDate  *date=[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY MMM,dd hh:mm a"];

            NSString *date_new=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
            NSLog(@"date is------ %@",date_new);

            newsCell.DateLabel.text=date_new;

            return newsCell;

        }

    }


    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
    {
        NSLog(@"-----------------array count is----------------------- %d",[self.NewsArray count]);
        if ([self.NewsArray count] == 0) 
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return [self.NewsArray count]+1;

    }

    - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
    {

        if(refreshing)
        {
            NSLog(@"I am a big BUG, hehe hahahaha");
            [spinner startAnimating];
            [self performSelector:@selector(getDetails:) withObject:@"0" afterDelay:1.0];
            //self.refreshing=NO;
        }


    }

    - (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{


        tempView.frame = CGRectMake(0,-80 - scrollView.contentOffset.y , 320,80);   
        if(scrollView.contentOffset.y < -60)
        {       
            lbl.text = @"Release to Update";
        }
        else
        {
            lbl.text = @"Pull down to Update";
        }

    }

    - (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
    {

        if(scrollView.contentOffset.y<-60 && !refreshing)
        {
            refreshing=YES;
        }


    }

`
```

Comment: @RahulVyas i am not getting any crash error while debugging.it is crashing in mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post your crash log, Did you tried to debug the code by placing break points? After a quick review of your code I noticed that you are not releasing the NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter initialized inside the - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method. This ll result in a huge memory leak. Also NSLog following variables to check whether they have expected values or nil.
`NSString *title=[object valueForKey:@"title"];
NSString *description=[object valueForKey:@"Description"];
NSString *dateString=[object valueForKey:@"NewsDate"];`

Comment: Hi adarsh i released that dateFormatter.but my problem is that app is not crashinh while debugging.But after debugging it is crashing.could u help me in solving this problem

Comment: Please send me the complete code. I will have a look into it.

Comment: Just after crashing Type bt and press enter in your console. It will give you more details about crash.

Comment: hi ayush i pasted code in the above link.please see .http://pastebin.com/bXispj8i

Answer (score 0):

try NSZombieEnabled environment variable and debug with device. you will find the actual reason for crash.